# WhatsApp Webhook Triggering Multiple Facebook Developer Apps

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have several applications set up within the Facebook Developers platform. One serves as a production app, while the other two are duplicates used solely for development. Each app is associated with a unique phone number and has its distinct webhook.

The challenge arises when I send a message to a specific phone number linked with my primary production app (let's say it's "123-456-7890"). Surprisingly, I noticed that webhook1 of the production app not only receives the notification but webhook2 of a different development app (App2) and webhook3 of another development app (App3) also get triggered.

As a temporary workaround, I've implemented a verification step within the webhook payload to match the phoneid with the configured phone number of the expected app and block any inconsistencies.